# iOS Flutter Xcode Error: Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have the following error:

[image]

My configuration is:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale es-419) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

In Xcode the error happend here:

[image]

I will really appreciate help